# Centering a table and the caption

Tags: tables

I can't center the table with the following code, but the caption is in the center:

```
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
       \caption{\textbf{State Table for Example 1}}
  \label{table: state table1}
\begin{tabular}{cc|cc}

x & y & X & Y \\ 
\hline
   $\bar{0}$  & $\bar{0}$ & 1 &1 \\ 
   0  & 1 & 0 &1 \\ 
   $\bar{1}$  & $\bar{1}$ & 0 & 0 \\ 
   1  & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 

  \end{tabular}
      \end{minipage}}
\end{table}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering

\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
       \caption{\textbf{State Table for Example 1}}
  \label{table: state table1}

\hfil % This is new 
\begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
x & y & X & Y \\ 
\hline
   $\bar{0}$  & $\bar{0}$ & 1 &1 \\ 
   0  & 1 & 0 &1 \\ 
   $\bar{1}$  & $\bar{1}$ & 0 & 0 \\ 
   1  & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 
  \end{tabular}
      \end{minipage}}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have centered the outer `box` that contains the `minipage` but the contents inside the `minipage` need another `\centering`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,showframe}  %% showframe just for demo
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering    %%% centers the following box
\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \centering              %% <-- this is for centering inside minipage
  \caption{\textbf{State Table for Example 1}}
  \label{table: state table1}
    \begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
      x & y & X & Y \\
       \hline
     $\bar{0}$  & $\bar{0}$ & 1 &1 \\
     0  & 1 & 0 &1 \\
     $\bar{1}$  & $\bar{1}$ & 0 & 0 \\
     1  & 0 & 1 &0 \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]